Kubuntu 24.04 fresh install not loading hardware drivers properly
EDIT || FIXED :
I'm terribly sorry... looks like i didn't (as i should have) double-check on Suse Tumbleweed properly as it wasn't pointing to the latest kernel yet(6.8.0-36-generic).
Just updated GRUB on Suse Tumbleweed once again, now it shows up on Kubuntu's entry, now it finally identifies my GPU & monitor properly... however... for some reason there was no longer a wayland session available, goes straight into the X11 one by default with no option to select an alternative.
Fixed by reinstalling sudo apt install plasma-workspace-wayland
All fixed & working now. Deeply sorry for the waste of time.
==========================================================
===========================
Hardware
cpu: AMD 5950X
gpu: AMD 7900XTX
MOBO: Asus b550-A with two 2tb nvme drives for SO (pci-e4.0 and pci-e3.0)
32gb ram 3600mhz
monitor: Gigabyte m32u (2160p,ips)
Previous steps
These days i'm trying to setup a multiboot machine, with Win10 on pci-e4.0 nvme plus six different linux distros on pci-e3.0, with one customized grub to handle boot for all SOs installed.
Worth mentioning it, because i've been testing how different distros "get along" with each other in terms of compatibility (and i mean, the usual issues with the way they - Arch/Ubuntu/Fedora/Suse - handle GRUB) and each and every time on every test before wiping pci-e3.0 nvm and start again from scratch... i installed Kubuntu 24.04. on it... and always worked perfectly fine (gpu & monitor brand & models properly displayed, wayland working, everything in perfect working order).
Current state
Finally settled on half a dozen linux distros, so i kept my Win10 install on pci-e4.0 nvme and installed those six linux distros on pci-e3.0.
Kubuntu 24.04 worked fine on current install, until i updated the system and was faced with this well known issue:
Kubuntu 24.04 Black Screen / Not Booting After Upgrade
which i fixed following up the suggestion there,(long story short, setting GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= to quiet) which worked fine.
Next boot... (and i'm writing this message from my Kubuntu 24.04. install)... GPU drivers aren't loaded, monitor drivers neither, can't select wayland/x11 session neither... it's like i'm stuck on some permanent safe-graphics mode.
Potential suspect
Since this is a multiboot (6 linux distros) drive with Kubuntu being installed in 3rd place and GRUB being controlled by the last distro installed (Suse Tumbleweed), i'm wondering if it might be this GRUB entry that's permanently redirecting towards safe-graphics mode.
I did sudo update-grub on any change while on Kubuntu 24.04, also updated GRUP on Suse Tumbleweed.
Any tip on what should i check next?
Thanks in advance

There never any monitor drivers only graphic card drivers.

Glad to see it is working for you. Could you please instead of a comment use the answer you own question option at the bottom of the question.

@David : strange... i have some other ubuntu-based distros with older kernels detecting my monitor as "generic"(doesn't allow me to set proper refresh rate nor color profiles), however on newer kernels it identifies brand & model with all settings available. PS: Done, just posted it as suggested, sorry for the mixup.

When a monitor is listed as generic one cause is that the HDMI cable is not bi directional so the monitor can not talk back to the OS. When the monitor info is listed it is a response from the monitor to a request from the OS.

However... the aforementioned OS/monitor interaction happened on the very same machine, same HDMI cable, same parts, same everything... just different (ubuntu-based) distros with older kernel version on it. Sorry for the offtopic.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm terribly sorry... looks like i didn't (and  i should) double-check on Suse Tumbleweed properly as it wasn't pointing to the latest kernel yet(6.8.0-36-generic).
Just updated GRUB on Suse Tumbleweed again, now it shows up on Kubuntu's entry, now it finally identifies my GPU & monitor properly... however... for some reason there was no longer a wayland session available, goes straight into X11  by default with no option to select an alternative.
Fixed by reinstalling sudo apt install plasma-workspace-wayland
All fixed & working now. Deeply sorry for the waste of time.
